# JavaFX controls along with Scenebuilder

Tags: java, css, user-interface, javafx

So, I'm working on a small project that involves JavaFX. I'm new to JavaFX and creating GUIS. I began to use Gluon's scenebuilder, and made the layout and added some external styles using .css. However, I need to implement a drag and drop feature for one of the anchorpanes I've used. You cannot do this via scenebuilder, thus I was trying to attain all the nodes through my code and make changes to the application, but the styles/changes are not applying. Is this because the are not hard copies of the objects that I've used in scenebuilder?

My code:

```
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("fxml file");
        FXMLLoader loader = load(getClass().getResource("fxml file");
        BorderPane pane = loader.load();
        ArrayList<Node> nodeList = new ArrayList<Node>();

        //Get All nodes of BorderPane
        for(Node node: pane.getChildren()){
            nodeList.add(node);
        }

        //Get TabPane from nodeList
        TabPane tabPane = (TabPane) nodeList.get(0);

        ObservableList<Tab> tabList = tabPane.getTabs();
        //Declare List for Tab Pane's anchorpanes
        ArrayList<Node> anchorPaneList = new ArrayList<Node>();
        //Retrieve tabPane anchorPanes
        for(Tab tab: tabList){
            anchorPaneList.add(tab.getContent());
        }

        //Retrieve the First AnchorPane
        AnchorPane ap1 = (AnchorPane) anchorPaneList.get(0);

        ap1.getStyleClass().add("turnRed");
```

My Css:

```
.turnRed {
 -fx-background-color: red;
}
```

Comment: You should use a [controller](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/fxml/doc-files/introduction_to_fxml.html#controllers) to do this. See also http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javafx/1580/fxml-and-controllers/5125/example-fxml#t=201703311551427885909 (Your code should work, assuming you actually display `pane` in a scene somewhere; however this style of navigating through the scene graph is not robust - you'll potentially need to rewrite all this code every time you change the layout.)

Comment: Furthermore there is no indication in the question that you use a CSS stylesheet containing a rule for `.turnRed`. Please create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to include it...

Comment: And, also, you seem to be loading the FXML twice. It's not clear what your `load(...)` method does, but you load the FXML once and call it `root`, and apparently load it again and call it `pane`. Is there a reason for that?

Comment: just assumed that the 2nd load would attain all the child nodes etc for each container. I originally started with Parent root, but I could not attain the children node that way.

Comment: But the second load will get a complete new set of controls. So if `root` is displayed in the UI, you will be calling methods (setting the style, etc) of controls that are not displayed in the UI....

Comment: I see, I will try that thanks!